# Aviary client side implementation vs needing a server side component

Tags: aviary

I'm planning on building an online image editor. I want to use aviary library for it. https://developers.aviary.com

Can someone explain me how I implement it? More specifically, do I need to send an image to their server in order to modify it? or I just do all the modifications on client side and then save that image to the server?

Answer (score 0):

The editor works by loading the image client-side via a public url, allowing the user to edit the photo in the browser. When the user saves, the image is POSTed to Aviary's server, where it's uploaded to a temporary storage location. You then get a url to that temporary image passed to you in the onSave callback, which you can use to save the image back to your own server.

See a full client-side integration here: https://developers.aviary.com/docs/web/example

Comment: if editing is done in the browser then why does it need to upload it to aviary server?

Comment: The upload to Aviary's servers is purely for developer convenience. Rather than having to deal with creating a cross-browser, client-side, multipart POST with the base64 canvas data your own server, then converting it into the appropriate image type, then uploading it to your own storage service, Aviary does all that for you and gives you back a temporary url that you can just download the image from.

Comment: If you want to do all of that yourself, you can, by calling: editor.getImageData(function(data) { // upload data to your service });